# Button event in Mono IronPython Winforms

Tags: python, python-2.7, winforms, mono, ironpython

I am trying to make an event upon button click, and that's using python coding in mono winforms. what i have done is to add button.click event and it's work perfectly when i press on the button but when i press anywhere in the form it's give an error [OnClick() takes exactly 3 arguments(2 given).] please check the picture below.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETH3.jpg)

please find the code below. please help.

```
class IForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'Buttons'

        self.Size = Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        close = Button()
        close.Text = "Close"
        close.Parent = self
        close.Location = Point(50, 50)      
        close.Click += self.OnClick
        self.CenterToScreen()    

    def OnClick(self, sender, args):
        self.Close()        
Application.Run(IForm())
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the event to buttonPressed and it's worked

```
class IForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'Buttons'

        self.Size = Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        close = Button()
        close.Text = "Close"
        close.Parent = self
        close.Location = Point(50, 50)      
        close.Click += self.buttonPressed
        self.CenterToScreen()    

    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        self.Close()        
Application.Run(IForm())
```